# angularjs- disable submit till all fields are filled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Submit button in the form should be disabled till all fields are filled but what i've noticed is when user inputs just the username the button comes alive .

```
<div class="list">
<form id="create" name="pw" method="post">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="kojobaah" ng-model="username" required>
</label>

   <label for="password">New Password
    <input type="password" name="user_password" ng-model="user_password" ng-required="confirm_password && !user-password" password-verify="confirm_pasword">
    <p ng-show="pw.user_password.$error.passwordVerify">Passwords do not match</p>
    <p ng-show="pw.user_password.$error.required">This field is required</p>
  </label>
</p>
 <p>
  <label for="password">Confirm Password
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" ng-model="confirm_password" ng-required="user_password && !confirm_password" password-verify="user_password"> 
    <p ng-show="pw.confirm_password.$error.passwordVerify">Passwords do not match</p>
    <p ng-show="pw.confirm_password.$error.required">This field is required</p>
  </label>
  <br />
  <p align="center"><button ng-disabled="create.$invalid" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="register()">Create Account</button></p>  
  </form>
  </div>
```

JS

```
.directive('passwordVerify', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                if (scope.confirm_password === scope.user_password) {
                    scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', true);
                    scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', true);
                } else if (scope.confirm_password !== scope.user_password) {
                    scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', false);
                    scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', false);
                }
            });
        }
     };
})
```

any help on how to make the button disabled till username is filled and password matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your form is `pw`, so that is the form you need to drill into for Angular's validity directive for the form as a whole.

Simply change:

```
<button ng-disabled="create.$invalid" 
        class="button button-balanced"
        ng-click="register()">
        Create Account
</button>
```

to:

```
<button ng-disabled="pw.$invalid" 
        class="button button-balanced"
        ng-click="register()">
        Create Account
</button>
```

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0zlN2TmEIbGQW5Mq7YJ0?p=preview

Update: Switching `ng-required` to simply `true` on the password fields, and moving the comparision logic to the `ng-disabled` directive on the button achieves the validation check required.

```
<button ng-disabled="pw.$invalid || (user_password != confirm_password)" 
        class="button button-balanced"
        ng-click="register()">
        Create Account
</button>
```

Comment: Just tested your answer but before the passwords are entered, the button becomes active

Comment: That's because the validation check is just that the input is filled, not that password A matches password B.

Comment: Can u help with the password too?

Comment: Updated answer and plnkr link

Answer (score 1):

Since the name of your form is **pw**, simply change your CREATE ACCOUNT button to:

```
<button ng-disabled="pw.$invalid" 
        class="button button-balanced"
        ng-click="register()">
        Create Account
</button>
```

Comment: I did that,  but when you only fill the username textbox,  the button becomes active.  It should remains disable till username is filled and password matches